# How to compare rational numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math

This is a homework problem. Given class "Rational" with two integer fields, numerator and denominator, write a function to compare two "Rational" instances. Let `r1 = a/b` and `r2 = c/d`. The trivial solution is to compare `a*d` and `b*c`. Can we do better?

Comment: What's the definition of "better"? It looks pretty optimal to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the cost of a branch is more than the cost of a multiplication, so it's not worth trying to be to clever apart from that. If by integers you mean int32, then promote to int64 to perform the multiplication; if you mean larger integers then you need to manage the multiplication using the usual mechanisms, at which point the assumptions about branches can be invalidated.

Comment: -2 (a*d) is equal to -2 (b*c).

Answer (score 4):

In the general case, no. If you expect to do a lot of comparisons, a preliminary processing step could take care of normalizing everything (by dividing both numerator and denominator by their gcd, and making the denominator positive), so that equality comparisons would compare a = c and b = d, but computing a*d = b*c is certainly not prohibitive by any means.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the sophisticated solution, convert each of the two fractions to a continued fraction (using a variant of the GCD algorithm). This simple algorithm generates one integer  at a time. Compare each pair of integers from the two partial continued fractions. If they are different, exit. Otherwise generate the next pair and continue while there are more.
For rationals, the sequence is finite, so it will terminate soon.
I believe this is the best method when a,b,c,d are big.

It has been proved that the continued fraction expansions for all square roots irrationals are recurring. So you can use this also to compare those irrationals, even if their binary computer representations would otherwise give you a wrong result (due to truncation).
That means that as soon as you detect the repetition in the pattern, you can terminate, proving equality of the two irrationals.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, the trivial solution is incorrect in case there are negative numbers allowed:

What about `r1=1/3` and `b=1/(-3)` which should both be a correct rational numbers. and of course mathematically it holds that:
1/(-3) < 1/3

However, the proposed solution yields `1*3 > 1*(-3)` which leads to the incorrect solution that `1/3 < 1/(-3)`.

I just ran into that problem during my Scala course :-) Still I don't have a good solution on that.

Maybe, like so often it helps to look into the BOOST-Library: There it says:

> The compare-with-rational operation does two double-sized GCD operations, two extra additions and decrements, and three comparisons in the worst case. (The GCD operations are double-sized because they are done in piecemeal and the interim quotients are retained and compared, whereas a direct GCD function only retains and compares the remainders.)

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/rational/rational.html

So far I didn't have the chance to investigate that code.

Cheers,
Felix

Meanwhile I had a look into the Boost code and it does the same like Liberius describes in his answer above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288890/2682209
So this is definitely the "correct" (but cumbersome) way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I do not like `a*d b*c` solution because it may lead to unnecessary integer overflow if some of numerators and denominators are big. Although I have no better solution.

Answer (score 1):

When I was dealing with fraction numbers, for example `rn1= a/b` and `rn2= c/d`  (rn1, rn2 being rational numbers where a,b,c,d are integers, I compared if `rn1 < rn2` by these following steps:

```
We have two fractions a/b and c/d.
Let Y = (a/b - c/d) 
      = (ad - bc)/(bd)
Now,
if Y > 0 then a/b > c/d 
if Y = 0 then a/b = c/d
if Y < o then a/b < c/d

Since bd is always positive, the sign of Y depends only on the
numerator (ad-bc). So we need to compute (ad-bc) only.
```

The logic of comparing this way is discussed here [in geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-compare-two-fractions/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java, then you can use the `java.math.BigInteger` class if and when you encounter overflow; otherwise, you can implement your own via byte-arrays.